# Middleware in Play framework (Java)

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.5

I have experience web programing   using express js framework 
and this is my first time  to learn playframework in java

how to make middleware in play framework

as ussualy i use express js  just add middleware in front of controller in routes

example like this

```
router.get('/all/:key' , user_mid.login, ctrl_post.all)
```

user_mid.login =  is my middleware 
ctrl_post.all =  is my controller method to handle the request

so how to make middleware in play framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play does not have a concept called middleware.

In Play Java, `Result`s are returned by classes extending the `Action` (or Controller) abstract class. Why am I telling you this? Well, because you can compose actions. One action can forward a request to the next action, then to the next, and the other way around with the response. Play has good support for this concept: [Action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition) .

This goes in three steps:

1. Define an action by extending (usually) `play.mvc.Action.Simple` .
2. Annotate the method in your controller with `@With`, and your newly crated class. That way you composed two actions. They are called in the order in which the `@With` annotations appear, if you have multiple.
3. (Optionally) Define your own annotation for an action.